# Is it safe to add 'allowfullscreen' param automatically for all iframes?

Tags: iframe

I embed external content via iframes on WordPress sites via shortcode like this:

```
[iframe src="http://path.to/page"]
```

and all other params (width, height, frameborder, etc) added automatically (while content parsing and executing for such shortcodes) because there is no need to specify them every time.

Some of iframe embeds are videos from YouTube or Vimeo which needs 'allowfullscreen' param for their iframe code.

So I decided to add 'allowfullscreen' automatically for every iframe on site (even not YouTube or Vimeo) for easier adding content.

**Is it safe to add 'allowfullscreen' param automatically for all iframes?**
Is there any possible problems with 'allowfullscreen' in all iframes on site?

Answer (score -1):

The `allowfullscreen` doesn't seem to pass the [W3C Validator Check](http://validator.w3.org/%E2%80%8E), even for YouTube; I get:

```
Line 129, Column 131: "allowfullscreen" is not a member of a group specified for any attribute
…bed/uIQFKwurSPM?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br />
```